# Compiling Apple frameworks for simple command line programs

Tags: objective-c, c, command-line, terminal

I have a simple program written in C and Objective-C. It consists of a few files that sit on my desktop which I compile from terminal using this:

`gcc -framework Foundation audio.m WavReader.m WavFileCreator.m -o audio`

I want to generate an audio file with my code and to do this need the AudioToolbox framework which I include in the .h file using

`#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

When I compile I get this error:

```
WavFileCreator.m: In function ‘createNewWAV’:
WavFileCreator.m:61: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AudioFileCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      _createNewWAV in cckeb4pu.o
  "_AudioFileWriteBytes", referenced from:
      _createNewWAV in cckeb4pu.o
  "_AudioFileClose", referenced from:
      _createNewWAV in cckeb4pu.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Ignore the error on line 61 which I believe is a separate issue. The other errors seem to do with not being able to access the framework. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to link the AudioToolbox framework with `-framework`:

```
$ gcc -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox audio.m WavReader.m WavFileCreator.m -o audio
```